# Getting cpu and memory usage for a period of time

Tags: android, shell, performance-testing

I have some old shell scripts that needs to be executed on an android device but the command to fetch the total cpu, memory and swap usage is top. More specific it is:

```
top -m 1 -d 1.0 -n $duration
```

Now I have been looking to find a replacement for this and I found out that I can use dumpsys. The problem what I have is that I want to give a timeout like this:

```
dumpsys -t 20 cpuinfo
```

I checked this site: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys.html but didn't find out why this doesn't work. Even when I try the help I get the same error

```
dumpsys --help
Can't find the service: --help
```

Does someone know what is going on? My current android version is 6.0.1 if this is important.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is true that dumpsys --help does not work. I think there is a mistake in their document. However, below works:

```
# adb shell dumpsys input
# adb shell dumpsys -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Add permission on your manifest "android.permission.DUMP".or 
There's another (hacky) way to access dumpsys without rooting your device - through adb shell.

This will require allowing USB debugging, and finding the port of the adb service.

Enable USB debugging on your device. This option is found under Settings -> Developer Options.

Connect your device to a PC, and run the following command from the PC's shell/command line: adb tcpip 12345. Then, from your devices shell, issue the command adb connect localhost:12345 from your application. You can now disconnect the device from USB. Alternatively, you can scan the ports on your device one by one without USB connection, using adb connect localhost: and find the port adb service is listening to.

Authorize USB debugging from the pop up confirmation dialog, if prompted. Check the "always" checkbox to do not require this step again.

Now, when you have access to the adb service, use adb shell dumpsys ... from your application code to get whatever service dump you need.